# How to make NSTextView scroll horizontally?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, horizontal-scrolling

so I was playing around with XCode and I was wondering if it was possible scroll an NSTextView horizontally.  I know that we can add a horizontal scroller to it through interface builder (or Xcode) but you still can't scroll horizontally even after adding it so any help would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you set the frame/bounds on the scroller? Those both need to be manually set for a scroller to work.

Comment: and how are you suppose to do that?

Comment: manually via code. set its frame to the size you'd like it to appear as, and the bounds to the total size of the content contained within.